# Laravel search engine using query but the thing is its not accurate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, search, laravel-5.3

I want to make it accurate first it should get data from tittle and than get data description I tried this but its not accurate and description is returned first.

Here is the site live [here is the demo](https://linknado.com/) example I want the movie George Lopez if I type only George other things are returned if I type full name  George Lopez this is working - help me.

```
<?php
use App\CommunityLink;
//use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

Route::get ( '/', function () {
    return view ( 'welcome' );
} );
Route::post ( '/search', function () {
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
    $user = CommunityLink::where ( 'title', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->orWhere ( 'description', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->get ();
    if (count ( $user ) > 0)
        return view ( 'welcome' )->withDetails ( $user )->withQuery ( $q );
    else
        return view ( 'welcome' )->withMessage ( 'No Details found. Try to search again !' );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works for you. Basically what it does is, it searches by title and by description and put results with matching titles on top of the result collection.

```
//define the keywords variable 
$q = '%'.$request->q.'%'; // '%'.Input::get ( 'q' ).'%'

//Run the query 
$result = Community::where('title', 'Like', '?')
->orWhere('description', 'Like', '?')
->orderByRaw("
    CASE WHEN title LIKE ? THEN 1
         WHEN description LIKE ? THEN 2
         ELSE 3 END
")
->setBindings([$q, $q, $q, $q])
->get();
```

We pass `$q` 4 times because we call it in 4 different places. 
This may not be the best way, but it gets the job done and pretty fast.

Now your results will be filter with matching title on top, followed by matching description.

Comment: Thank's For the answer but i am having this error now Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: In my code I gave you a choice. You don't use both. just one. ok. Change in your code the line where you wrote `$q = '%'.$request->q.'%';` Change it to `$q = '%'.Input::get ( 'q' ).'%';`. It works fine. I tested everything

Comment: it working thanks a lot do you know something about auto compleate in laravel drop down with quarry i searched a lot but did not find anything useful for me

Comment: If it's working mark my answer and upvote me. If you want to have autocomplete, you will have to use something called `Bootstrap Typeahead`.

Comment: I have voted up for you and please help me in Bootstrap Typeahead with my db i will say my friends to vote you up nearly 5 friends.but i want that auto compleate getting that from db thanks in advance